# jQuery UI, on accordionactivate determine if panel opening or closing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm actually working on a jQuery UI accordion and I'm trying to find how I can know when the panel is opening or closing so I can execute a different function for both events.

```
$("#accordion").bind('accordionactivate', function(event, ui) {
  $(ui.newPanel).find('.itemChildren').empty();
  var index = $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active");
  alert($.isEmptyObject(ui.oldPanel));
  if( index !== false){
    var item = {};
    item[Settings.id_item] = Tree.getTreeItemId(ui.newPanel);
    Tree.displayChildren(item, Settings, Url);
  }
});
```

I tried to watch if the object is empty: no

I tried to look if the active index is false: only false when the last panel closed

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best way to do it but it works for me, I just verify if the class from the newPanel exists:

```
$("#accordion").bind('accordionactivate', function(event, ui) {
  if(typeof $(ui.newPanel).attr('class') === 'undefined'){
    $(ui.oldPanel).find('.itemChildren').empty();
  } else {
    var item = {};
    item[Settings.id_item] = Tree.getTreeItemId(ui.newPanel);
    Tree.displayChildren(item, Settings, Url);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but I came across it today.  From the accordion documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate):

> If the accordion is currently collapsed, ui.oldHeader and ui.oldPanel
>   will be empty jQuery objects. If the accordion is collapsing,
>   ui.newHeader and ui.newPanel will be empty jQuery objects.

Therefore, if ui.newHeader is not empty, then the accordion is about to be opening.  Alternatively, if ui.oldHeader is not empty, then the accordion is about to be collapsing.  The code below worked well for me:

```
$("#accordion" ).on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.newHeader.size()) {
        console.log("Activating");
    } else if (ui.oldHeader.size()) {
        console.log("Deactivating");
    }
});
```